# Conditional type constraint parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have a class, Container<T>, which has a ContainerContents<T>. The Container actually takes two type constraint parameters Container<TContainer,TContents> - TContainer being the type of the container, and TContents being the type of contents it accepts.

I want to ensure that if TContainer is X or derived from X, then TContents will also be X or derived from X, but that TContents does not have to equal TContainer.

I'm trying to express the following kinds of things.

- Things that can be carried around (Swag), like a pencil.
- Things that cannot be carried (BaseObject), like a tree.
- Things that can hold other things (Container)
- Containers that cannot be carried, like a bank vault.
- Carriable Containers (like a backpack).

If a container can be carried, then its contents must be carriable too. But, just because the Container is a backpack doesn't mean it can only carry backpacks.

I want to be able to code:

- `var ringWorld = new Container<BigRing, CivicWork>();`
- `var pickleKnox = new Container<BankVault, Pickle>();`
- `var swagBag = new Container<ToteBag, Swag>();`
- `var tomeBag = new Container<ToteBag, Book>();`

but not `var treeBag = new Container<Bag, Tree>();`

Here's my skeletal setup.

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    private readonly string _name;

    protected BaseObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

```
public class Swag : BaseObject
{
    private readonly int _weight;

    public Swag(string name, int weight):base(name)
    {
        _weight = weight;
    }

    public int Weight { get { return _weight; } }
}
```

```
/* I like the flexibility of i.e.: Container<BankVault,Pickles> 
but if the container itself is carriable (Swag), then its contents 
are by nature also carriable. */

public class Container<TContainer,TContents> : BaseObject 
    where TContainer:BaseObject 
    where TContents:BaseObject, or Swag if TContainer:(Swag or derived from Swag)
{
    ContainerContents<TContents> _contents;

    public Container(string name, int maxItems):base(name)
    {

        /* if (TContainer is derived from Swag) { TContents must be too } */

        _contents = new ContainerContents<TContents>(maxItems);
    }
}
```

```
public class ContainerContents<T> : List<T> where T : BaseObject
{
    int _maxItems;

    public ContainerContents(int maxItems)
    {
        _maxItems = maxItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work.

I would create the following interfaces:

```
interface ICarryable { }
interface IContainer<T> { }
```

Then you could implement the following classes:

```
class Backpack<T> : ICarryable, IContainer<T>
where T : ICarryable 
{  }

class Vault<T> : IContainer<T>
{  }
```

If a class implements `ICarryable`, it can be carried. If it doesn't implement that interface, it is a fixed object that can't be carried.
This describes more precisely, what is going on. Your generic `Container` class doesn't communicate, that the container is of type `TContainer` and its contents are of type `TContainerContents`.

To avoid violating the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you can still create a generic container base class, your vault and backpack inherit from. Making it abstract ensures, that no one uses it instead of your concrete implementations.